# What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the JavaScript functions `decodeURIComponent` and `decodeURI`?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

To explain the difference between these two let me explain the difference between `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`.

The main difference is that:

- The `encodeURI` function is intended for use on the full URI.
- The `encodeURIComponent` function is intended to be used on .. well .. URI components that is 
  any part that lies between separators (; / ? : @ & = + $ , #).

So, in `encodeURIComponent` these separators are encoded also because they are regarded as text and not special characters.

Now back to the difference between the decode functions, each function decodes strings generated by its corresponding encode counterpart taking care of the semantics of the special characters and their handling.

Comment: Another vital difference is that unescape does not handle multi-byte UTF-8 sequences whereas decodeURI[Component] does: `decodeURIComponent("%C3%A9") == "é"; unescape("%C3%A9") == "Ã©";`

Comment: IMHO, giving some examples would be very useful

Comment: Note that `decodeURI("%C3%A9") == "é"`. Unless you have some specific reason to NOT ALLOW encoding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the `decodeURI()` will be the best option because browsers usually send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The most common difference is handling `+`.

Comment: It should be okay to use `encodeURIComponent()` for everything but always decode with `decodeURI()`. For the output of `encodeURIComponent()` it doesn't matter if you use `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()`. If you need to handle browser emitted query string, parsing that correctly may need use of `decodeURI()` instead of `decodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 134):

encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent() is almost always the pair you want to use, for concatenating together and splitting apart text strings in URI parts.

encodeURI in less common, and misleadingly named: it should really be called fixBrokenURI. It takes something that's nearly a URI, but has invalid characters such as spaces in it, and turns it into a real URI. It has a valid use in fixing up invalid URIs from user input, and it can also be used to turn an IRI (URI with bare Unicode characters in) into a plain URI (using %-escaped UTF-8 to encode the non-ASCII).

Where encodeURI should really be named fixBrokenURI(), decodeURI() could equally be called potentiallyBreakMyPreviouslyWorkingURI(). I can think of no valid use for it anywhere; avoid.

Comment: decodeURI(encodeURI('%20 ')) gives '%20 ' correctly in ie, chrome and firefox, just wondering from which browser/version the incorrect result you observed?

Comment: Might have been broken in 2009 but modern browser caught up in the meantime (my guess).

Answer (score 83):

```
js> s = "http://www.example.com/string with + and ? and & and spaces";
http://www.example.com/string with + and ? and & and spaces
js> encodeURI(s)
http://www.example.com/string%20with%20+%20and%20?%20and%20&%20and%20spaces
js> encodeURIComponent(s)
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fstring%20with%20%2B%20and%20%3F%20and%20%26%20and%20spaces
```

Looks like [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) produces a "safe" URI by encoding spaces and some other (e.g. nonprintable) characters, whereas [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) additionally encodes the colon and slash and plus characters, and is meant to be used in query strings. The encoding of + and ? and & is of particular importance here, as these are special chars in query strings.

Answer (score 37):

As I had the same question, but didn't find the answer here, I made some tests in order to figure out what the difference actually is.
I did this, since I need the encoding for something, which is not URL/URI related.

- `encodeURIComponent("A")` returns "A", it does not encode "A" to "%41"
- `decodeURIComponent("%41")` returns "A".
- `encodeURI("A")` returns "A", it does not encode "A" to "%41"
- `decodeURI("%41")` returns "A".

-That means both can decode alphanumeric characters, even though they did not encode them. However...

- `encodeURIComponent("&")` returns "%26".
- `decodeURIComponent("%26")` returns "&".
- `encodeURI("&")` returns "&".
- `decodeURI("%26")` returns "%26".

Even though encodeURIComponent does not encode all characters, decodeURIComponent can decode any value between %00 and %7F.

*Note: It appears that if you try to decode a value above %7F (unless it's a unicode value), then your script will fail with an "URI error".*

Comment: Note: There is a typo in first decodeURIComponent (m instead of n). I cannot correct it, because I have to edit at least 6 characters.

Comment: In other words the decode functions will throw an exception if the decoded bytes do not make for a valid UTF-8 sequence. Once you go beyond %7F, you are into multi-byte sequences. So for example %D0%B0 is valid, but %80 is not.

Answer (score 31):

> **`encodeURIComponent()`**
>
> Converts the input into a URL-encoded
>   string
>
> **`encodeURI()`**
>
> URL-encodes the input, but
>   assumes a full URL is given, so
>   returns a valid URL by not encoding
>   the protocol (e.g. *http://*) and
>   host name (e.g.
>   *www.stackoverflow.com*).

`decodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURI()` are the opposite of the above

Answer (score 15):

decodeURIComponent will decode URI special markers such as &, ?, #, etc, decodeURI will not.

Answer (score 6):

encodeURIComponent 
Not Escaped:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

encodeURI()
Not Escaped:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Answer (score 0):

**Encode URI:**

The encodeURI() method does not encodes:

```
, / ? : @ & = + $ * #
```

Example

```
URI: https://my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab
Encoded URI: https://my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab
```

**Encode URI Component:**

The encodeURIComponent() method also encodes:

```
, / ? : @ & = + $ #
```

Example

```
URI: https://my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab
Encoded URI: https%3A%2F%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

For More: [W3Schoools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)