# Decoding URL parameters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, decoding, url-parameters

This should be a simple task, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a basic string that is being passed through as a query string parameter like this one: `This+is+a+message+with+spaces`. I would like to decode that parameter using JavaScript to `This is a message with spaces`, but I cannot seem to get it to decode.

I've tried `decodeURI('This+is+a+message+with+spaces')` but the result still contains the `+` signs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function

Comment: The URL needs to be encoded to be decoded ;)

Comment: Locrizak, `decodeURIComponent('This+is+a+message+with+spaces')` still returns `This+is+a+message+with+spaces`. `encodeURIComponent('This+is+a+message+with+spaces')` returns `This%2Bis%2Ba%2Bmessage%2Bwith%2Bspaces`. I must be missing something because I'm not seeing how this is solving my problem.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes it is true that decodeURIComponent function doesn't convert + to space. So you have to replace the + using replace function.

Ideally the below solution works.

```
var str_name = 'This+is+a+message+with+spaces';
decodeURIComponent((str_name + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
```

Comment: This is the better answer. `encodeURIComponent` may well choose not to encode spaces to `+`, preferring `%20`, but the URI may come from somewhere else, and `+` is a perfectly valid encoding for a space that for unknown reasons JS's `decodeURIComponent` decides to ignore.

Comment: + is not a valid uri encoding for space. some websites just choose to replace spaces in urls with `+`, `-`, `_`, etc. because it's more readable, but it's not standardized

Answer (score 34):

Like it was pointed out already, `decodeURI` function doesn't convert `+` to space, ***but*** there are some things worth to realize here:

- `decodeURI` is meant to be used for whole URI, i.e. it doesn't decode separators like `?`, `&`, `=`, `+`, etc.
- for decoding parameters `decodeURIComponent` should be used
  (worth to have a look at: [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/747641/1168156) )
- string that you are trying to decode might actually contain `+` encoded as `%2B`, thus you should not replace `+` after the conversion since you might lost `+` signs that you actually want there, e.g. `something?num=%2B632+905+123+4567` should become:
  `something?num=+632 905 123 4567`
  since you are probably going to extract the number: `+632 905 123 4567`

So the correct way to do this is:

```
var str = 'something?num=%2B632+905+123+4567';
decodeURIComponent( str.replace(/\+/g, '%20') );
```

Answer (score 29):

The plus sign is not encoded/decoded. To see the decode function working, you need to pass a encoded URI first. Take a look:

```
encodeURI( "http://www.foo.com/bar?foo=foo bar jar" )
```

Will generate: `http://www.foo.com/bar?foo=foo%20bar%20jar`, i.e., the encoded URI.

```
decodeURI( "http://www.foo.com/bar?foo=foo%20bar%20jar" )
```

Will generate: `http://www.foo.com/bar?foo=foo bar jar`, i.e., the decoded URI.

Answer (score 12):

The below code will decode and gives you the params in form of objects

```
export function getParamsFromUrl(url) {
    url = decodeURI(url);
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
        let params = url.split('?');
        let eachParamsArr = params[1].split('&');
        let obj = {};
        if (eachParamsArr && eachParamsArr.length) {
            eachParamsArr.map(param => {
                let keyValuePair = param.split('=')
                let key = keyValuePair[0];
                let value = keyValuePair[1];
                obj[key] = value;
            })
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created my own string methods to support the needed encoding/decoding. These methods will handle the + encoding and decoding properly, allowing you to have plusses (+) in your string and still have the original spaces be encoded as +'s.

```
String.prototype.plusEncode = function() {
    return encodeURIComponent(this).replace(/\%20/gm,"+");
}

String.prototype.plusDecode = function() {
    return decodeURIComponent(this.replace(/\+/gm,"%20"));
}
```