# Why can't "decodeURIComponent" or "decodeURI" decode "hello+world" to "hello world" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, urldecode

According to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

"+" is a valid URL encoding token.

If so, why can't `decodeURIComponent` or `decodeURI` decode "hello+world" to "hello world"?

If "+" is valid, surely, there has to be a built-in function in JavaScript that can convert "hello+world" to "hello world"?

Comment: a solution and explanation has already been provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042592/decoding-url-parameters-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The behavior of `decideURIComponent` is defined as](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.2) "inverse" operation of `encodeURIComponent`:

> The `decodeURIComponent` function computes a new version of a `URI` in which each escape sequence and UTF-8 encoding of the sort that might be introduced by the `encodeURIComponent` function is replaced with the character that it represents.

And `encodeURIComponent` does not replace spaces with `+`, but with `%20`.

(similar for `decodeURI`)

> If "+" is valid, surely, there has to be a built-in function in JavaScript that can convert "hello+world" to "hello world"?

Of course there is:

```
"hello+world".replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `encodeURIComponent` would encode a space to `%20` so you would get `hello%20world`. If you want to replace `+` characters I would suggest using regex