# How to check all checkboxes if they have value in url?

Tags: jquery

I have this url :

```
http://test.dev/search?publishing_types%5B%5D=Selling&prop_category%5B%5D=Apartment+%26+housing&priceFrom=0&priceTo=300000&areaFrom=0&areaTo=300000&yearFrom=1900&yearTo=2017
```

In fuction i check full url and i want to add checkbox for that value if exists in url. Any suggesion?

```
  function existingUrl(fullUrl){
          $('.dataurl').each(function(){
            var hasValue =  fullUrl.indexOf($(this).val());
            if(hasValue != -1)
              this.checked = true;

        });
      }
```

HTML:

```
  @foreach($prop_types as $index => $prop_type)
     <p class="customCheckBox no-padding-left">
        <input type="checkbox" class="preventUncheck dataurl" name="publishing_types[]" id="toggle-on{{ $index }}" value="{{ $prop_type }}" >

        <label for="toggle-on{{ $index }}" class="checkboxTitle">{{ $prop_type }}</label>
     </p>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Adding some html will be helpful.

Comment: I updated my question, they are all same

Comment: it's already working ! What's the problem?

Comment: problem is when value is from two or more words i get like this Apartment+%26+housing and i dont get proper value

Comment: Please remove the horizontal scrollbars. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the clean text you need to decode the URI and replace any remaining codification. Assuming you have a string variable you can do this as below.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042592/decoding-url-parameters-with-javascript) for a longer explanation.

```js
var str = 'Apartment+%26+housing';
console.log('value=' + decodeURIComponent( str.replace(/\+/g, '%20') ));
```