# COOKIE created in php is misread in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have the following problem, I create a cookie in PHP and then read it in javascript and print it and this happens. I do not know how to correct it. Please help.

I read the cookie in javascript:

```
var micookie = (document.cookie.indexOf('resultado=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; resultado=')[1].split(';')[0]);
```

So he created the cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie("resultado","success",time() + 1, "/kira");
```

And it prints like this, as you can see in the image

```
Cerraste+sessi%C3%B3n
```

Code that creates the notification

```
var i = -1;
var toastCount = 0;
var $toastlast;


var micookie = (document.cookie.indexOf('resultado=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; resultado=')[1].split(';')[0]);
var micookietipo = (document.cookie.indexOf('tipo_result=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; tipo_result=')[1].split(';')[0]);
micookietipo = decodeURIComponent((micookietipo + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'))
var micookiedesc = (document.cookie.indexOf('desc_result=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; desc_result=')[1].split(';')[0]);
micookiedesc = decodeURIComponent((micookiedesc + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'))


function alerta() {
  var shortCutFunction = micookie;
  var msg = micookiedesc || '';
  var title = micookietipo || '';
  var $showDuration = $(300);
  var $hideDuration = $(1000);
  var $timeOut = $(2000);
  var $extendedTimeOut = $(500);
  var toastIndex = toastCount++;
  var addClear = $('#addClear').prop('checked');
  toastr.options = {
    closeButton: false,
    debug: false,
    newestOnTop: false,
    progressBar: true,
    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' || 'toast-top-right',
    preventDuplicates: true,
    onclick: null
  };
  toastr.options.showEasing = 'swing';
  toastr.options.hideEasing = 'linear';
  toastr.options.showMethod = 'fadeIn';
  toastr.options.hideMethod = 'fadeOut';
  var $toast = toastr[shortCutFunction](msg, title); // Wire up an event handler to a button in the toast, if it exists
  $toastlast = $toast;

  if (typeof $toast === 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
};

if (typeof micookie !== 'undefined' && typeof micookietipo !== 'undefined' && typeof micookiedesc !== 'undefined') {
  alerta();
}
```

VALIDATE.PHP

```
    <?php
    $error = $_COOKIE['resultado'];

    if($error == 'error'){
    header("location: ../../index.php");
    } else {
    require_once "../biblioteca.php";
    session_start();

    $db = ConectaDb($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

    $nombre=recoge("nombre");
    $email=recoge("email");
    $password=recoge("password");

    $consulta="SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre='$nombre' AND email='$email' AND password='$password'";

    $result = $db->query($consulta);

    if (!$result) {
            print "<p>Error en la consulta.</p>\n";
    } 
    elseif ($result->fetchColumn() == 0) {
            setcookie("resultado","error",time() + 1, "/kira");
            setcookie("tipo_result","Datos incorrectos",time() + 1, "/kira");
            setcookie("desc_result","Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",time() + 1, "/kira");
            header("Location: ../../index.php");

    } 
    else {
            $consulta =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
            $result = $db->query($consulta); 
            if (!$result) {
                print "    <p>Error en la consulta.</p>\n"; print "\n";
            } else {
                $consulta =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
                $result = $db->query($consulta); 
                foreach ($result as $valor) {
                $tipo_usuario = $valor['tipo_usuario'];
                $foto = $valor['foto'];

                if($tipo_usuario == "admin"){  
                    setcookie("resultado","success",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    setcookie("tipo_result","Bienvenido Administrador $nombre",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    setcookie("desc_result","Has iniciado sessión correctamente",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    $_SESSION['tipo_user'] = 'administrador';
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $nombre;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['fotoperfil'] = $foto;

                                        $carpeta = '../resources/musica/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/voz/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/luz/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/comida/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/foto/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                        header("Location: ../../panelcontrol_admin.php");
                return;
                }
                elseif($tipo_usuario=="user"){
                    setcookie("resultado","success",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    setcookie("tipo_result","Bienvenido Usuario $nombre",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    setcookie("desc_result","Has iniciado sessión correctamente",time() + 1, "/kira");
                    $_SESSION['tipo_user'] = 'usuario';
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $nombre;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['fotoperfil'] = $foto;

                                        $carpeta = '../resources/musica/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/voz/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/luz/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/comida/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                                        $carpeta = '../resources/foto/'.$nombre;
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
                    }
                        header("Location: ../../panelcontrol_user.php");
                return;
                }
                }
            }

    }    
        $db = null;
    }
?>
```

Comment: `time() + 1` means the cookie is destroy after one second

Comment: I know, i need this, is working this. Not working text correctly

Comment: Try and set it for longer and see if you can read it in PHP. And include more PHP code. We need to see everything up to the setcookie function

Comment: PHP is setting the cookie on a subdirectory. I suspect what you're seeing is a cookie from the root directory because the subdirectory cookie has expired.

Comment: The setcookie is up, is all here. the content of cookie is this Cerraste Sesión, but JAVASCRIP read this, print other text, this Cerraste + sessi% C3% B3n

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but what's the point of `positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' || 'toast-top-right',`? That's the same as `positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',`

Comment: Make your cookie last for at least an hour while you're debugging. Get yourself the browser extension called Edit This Cookie, available for either Firefox or Google Chrome. Keep in mind that many cookies are "HttpOnly" meaning there's no way for your Javascript to read their values. You can also look at the server response in the Network tab of your browser dev tools.

Comment: jejejej this is true, he escaped me

Comment: Again, please include more of the PHP. Everything until setcookie function. Setcookie is a header function and can't run if you have output prior. So, post the PHP code

Comment: Is that the real PHP code? The result you're seeing would come from `setcookie("resultado", "Cerraste sessión");`, not `setcookie("resultado", "success");`

Comment: ready new php file

Comment: I still don't see where you're setting the `resultado` cookie to anything other than `success` or `error`. `Cerraste sessión` doesn't appear anywhere in the updated question.

Comment: There's an accented character in `setcookie("desc_result","Has iniciado sessión correctamente",time() + 1, "/kira");` is that the cookie that's really giving you problems?

Comment: It works in the following way, I send a cookie with the name of the result to collect it in the js of the alert and the content of that cookie, Cerraste Sessión is the value that is sent through the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the string in javascript like so:

```
var micookie = (document.cookie.indexOf('resultado=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; resultado=')[1].split(';')[0]);

decodeURIComponent((micookie + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'))
```

Comment: I will try now. Thanks for this

Comment: Your welcome. if this answer is what you seek please mark it as best answer. thanks @DavidPricop

Comment: What does this have to do with it? The problem isn't with encoding, it's that the value is totally wrong.

Comment: @Barmar no the value isn't wrong. I tested it and it turns out it's about encoding. because David is using other characters than normal English alphabet

Comment: The cookie is supposed to contain `success`. What special character is in that?

Comment: We're talking about `setcookie("resultado","success",time() + 1, "/kira");` aren't we?

Comment: this is the actual result of that Cerraste sessión this is the special character ' ó ';
the cookie is set correctly and then destroyed. so he could retrieve the cookie but in a deformed shape. so my solution is to reform it. if you have a better approach please answer it better. @Barmar

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, but I get this Cerraste+sessión -> I get + instead of space

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042592/decoding-url-parameters-with-javascript You have to translate `+` to space yourself.

Comment: @DavidPricop  I edited my answer with replacing + with space. Hope it would help.

Comment: As mentioned in the question I linked to, you should do the `replace()` before calling `decodeURIComponent`, not after.

Comment: @David Pricop my bad sorry. I edited again and tested it. it should work now.

Comment: @DavidPricop do the replacment before decoding. Look at my answer again