# Why are non-language related global objects included in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was reading Definitive JavaScript by Flanagan where he lists all JavaScript Global Objects defined by the language.

However 5 (of about 20) of these seem to be non-language related:

```
decodeURI
encodeURI
decodeURIComponent
encodeURIComponent
JSON
```

Why are these considered part of the language when URI and JSON are more of a browser-server thing?

**Reference**

[Difference between decodeURI and decodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri)

Comment: They're not really browser related, they're protocol related. The URI doesn't change based on the browser, it's a necessary component of the http request.

Comment: Of course decoding could be considered server-side. The point was that most of the globals are language related - Object, Function, String, Number, Math, etc...

Comment: Javascript was designed from the start to be a browser scripting language, and was designed in a hurry. There are quite a few things in there which would probably have been implemented differently if it had been foreseen that it would have become such an important language both inside and outside of the browser.

Comment: I would not stick with details like this. Javascript has a couple of things that are supposed not to be designed in that way they was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `encodeXXX` and  `decodeXXX` methods were introduced by Microsoft in the IE5.5 (followed by Netscape 6) and later included on the revision 3/1999 of the ECMA-262 spec. 
JSON was introduced later and today is supported by all major browsers and is included on the revision 5/2011 of the ECMA-262 spec.

Those methods were not part of the original language and <strike>maybe</strike> they should not be in the global namespace. Like `AJAX`, those methods were introduced by a specific vendor and later adopted by the others, without a rigorous and formal process. Just one more aspect of the JavaScript's beautiful ugliness.