# URIencode and colon

Tags: javascript, uri, uriencoding

colon is a character which can be encoded to '%3A' as per many sites and when I try to encode using `URIencode` it is not working

for example if I try to encode like `URIencode(':');` then nothing happens. colon is returned. Why is this?? can someone help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look @ [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `encodeURI()` encodes special characters, except:

`, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

You should use this instead `encodeURIComponent(':');`

This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the characters skipped by `encodeURI()`