# How Can I use colon (:) with vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My url re-updating after the push 
I want to make this url:

```
www.abc.com/istanbul-taksim-otelleri?checkin=2019-05-08&checkout=2019-05-16&filters=meal_types:full,half,etc;stars:1,2,4
```

```
const query = {
  checkin: '2019-05-08',
  checkout: '2019-05-16',
  filters:'meal_types:full,half,etc;stars:1,2,4'
}
 this.router.push({query})
```

after this gettin like this

```
www.abc.com/istanbul-taksim-otelleri?checkin=2019-05-08&checkout=2019-05-16&filters=meal_types%3Afull,half,etc%3Bstars%3A1,2,4
```

do you have any idea ? how can fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URIencode and colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872629/uriencode-and-colon)

Answer (score 0):

See https://w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp - `%3A` is just a URL-encoded colon. URL-encoding Strings is standard practice, and in most cases required in order to make a valid URL.

If you need to decode a URL, something like [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) could work for you, e.g.:

```js
const uri = 'www.example.com/:";[]}'

const encodedURI = encodeURIComponent(uri)
console.log(encodedURI)

const decodedURI = decodeURIComponent(encodedURI)
console.log(decodedURI)
```

Comment: unfortunately it's about vue-router, query is correct but after it's self-updating

Comment: Yeah I think that's just standard behaviour, not specific to Vue... Could you not decode the URL from whatever route you end up hitting? Browsers won't treat the URL any differently whether it's encoded or not (unless unencoded it makes it an invalid URL).