# Remove Special Character from google chrome URL

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

try to run below url :

```
http://seaway.fulba.com

search word :- Hello Hi
```

Chrome add special character %20 instead of space, I want keep word as it is (Hello Hi) in the url what ever is search there.

I am passing url using html5 pushstate function. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: spaces are not valid in urls. Any browser that is showing spaces is just encoding them to %20 in the background. In your code you would reverse this encoding

Comment: @amit , It's not possible to set space as `" "` in address bar. Use decodeURI function in your javascript. Problem solved.

Comment: take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show ur your code or try [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for this like,

```
$url=urldecode($yoururl);
echo $url;
```

And when passing your search string in pushstate use [window.unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) or [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: Good. But he is using in html5 pushstate. So, put javascript for his. up vote for `decodeURI()`.

Comment: @amit show me your code of search button click which changes your url(pushstate)

Comment: You need to use decodeURI in `document.ready()` like `$('#gsc-i-id1').val(decodeURI(param));` currently it is not working in FF too.

Comment: function search_load()
     {
         $( ".custom" ).remove();
   
   //$( "#custom").html( " " );
   searchme=$("#gsc-i-id1").val();
   if ($('#showImages').is(":checked"))
   {
     showImages=$("#showImages").val();
   }
   else{
    showImages="no";
   } ajax function $(".banner").show();
                                 if(searchme!=window.location){
                                       window.history.pushState({path:searchme},'',"/?r="+searchme);
                                                            }
     return false;
     }

Comment: before i pushstate url it is alert ok like hello hi, but after pushing url it added special character there

Comment: Try to use `window.unescape` instead of `decodeURI`. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible since space is an invalid character in a URL/I.

The `ASCII` hex code of the  `space` character `20`, therefore you see the encoded space as `%20`and an encoded `'` as `%27`.

To reuse this in javascript you should use:

```
var str = decodeURI(URL_STRING);
```

In your case that would be:

```
var urlRValue = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
// "Hello%20Hi"
var str = decodeURI(urlRValue);
// "Hello Hi"
```

Comment: can you more specify it. is it possible what exactly i want? because it is working good in mozila

Comment: Sorry, but I beg to differ, if you take a look at the value of `window.location.search.split('=')[1]` in firefox, it displays also "Hello%20hi". Or another test: copy the url and paste it into notepad (or any plain text editor), you will see the `%20`. Firefox internally transforms the %20 and **only shows** it as a ` ` (space) character. But if you access it via `js` you'll always get `%20`

Comment: so above functioan can be achieve my goal to keep space as it is in chrome ?

Comment: Again: There are no spaces in a `url`, only `%20`-s. Firefox does some magic to show ` ` (space).`decodeURI` transforms encoded urls into normal strings `decodeURI('%20')` produces `" "`. Read more on: [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) or [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) and the [differences between them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri). Maybe that will help you