# I have problems in use unicode in java scriptn

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I'm beginner in Javascript, I have a url containing unicode like below:

```
/Solutions/راه-کار-جامع-امنیت-اطلاعات
```

Now I need to read the path name by following code

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')
```

and in the output I have this

> ```
> "", "Solutions", "%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7…%D8%AA->%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA"
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Those are the properly URL-encoded values for the characters outside of the ASCII range that are not allowed directly in a URL. If you want the original characters again, then URL-decode either the single values each, or the URL before you split it. Go look up `decodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

The unicode text is url-encoded. This means that the unicode characters are translated to codes that are safe to use as a url. You can revert this using the `decodeURIComponent` or the `decodeURI` function.

The difference between these two is already nicely explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri). In your case you will most likely use `decodeURIComponent` after you performed the split.