# How to replace / except in http://

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I need to replace `%2f` with `/`, except in `http://`.

Example:

```
var str = "http://locahost%2f";
str = str.replace(/%2f/g, "/");
```

Somehow I got `str` to output `http:/locahost/`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have to do this? Can you post more code? There probably is a better way.

Comment: The code works fine, If you're doing this in a bookmarklet, make sure you're escaping your code properly.

Comment: You could look for the `://` string and replace everything after that string. Using string `split` method for example.

Comment: By the way, when I execute your code in Firefox console, it gives me the good output. Are you sure nothing is missing in your question?

Comment: This question is fishy. Why did you even mention that http:// should be excluded? It obviously doesn't contain the string "%2f"

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

### What should be used

You should use `decodeURIComponent` or `decodeURI` functions to decode encoded strings like yours. For example, `decodeURIComponent("http://locahost%2f")` will return `http://localhost/`.

That being said, `decodeURIComponent` should be used to decode components of a URI and not a full URI like `http://locahost/`.

You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri), it explains what is the difference between `decodeURIComponent` and `decodeURI` and when each should be used.

### A workaround

As the first `/` are not encoded, it makes it difficult to find a Javascript functions doing exactly what you want. A working solution to decode your `%2f` after `http://` would be to use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split).

Working example:

```
var encoded = "http://localhost%2f";
var encodedArray = str.split("://");
var decoded = encodedArray[0] + "://" + encodedArray[1].replace(/%2f/g, "/");
```

Comment: I don't understand why splitting is necessary. The string "%2f" doesn't exist in "http://"

Comment: Then what is the question about?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the question is. It seems nothing is broken in the first place. Your answer is great! But the question is unanswerable because the output is already correct.

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
str = str.replace("%2f", "/");
```

Comment: Ya, there's some weird escaping going on

Comment: Running this code in my browsers console worked, and I can't find an instance where is doesn't.  
`"http://locahost%2f".replace("%2f", "/");`

Comment: Yeah, but i also can't find any instance where the question's code doesn't have the exact same output. Are you familiar with regex in JavaScript?

Comment: If you need to use regex , I can't help. As far as I can tell, using "replace" without regex works.