# Firebase downloadURL invalid URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

After generated downloadURL in firebase using:

```
{ 
 ... 

 let url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

 ...
}
```

the url content is something similar:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sd2ds-.23.appspot.com/o/Usr%2FEls%2 ...

No worries in using in the browser or HTML tags, however, when I try to use the url generated in photoURL an error is generated:

**The photoURL field must be a valid URL.**

I already tried use **decodeURI(url)** but nothing changed.

Firebase generates the url with %2 in **/** (slash) place and seems be the problem.

Any glue?

Thanks

Comment: **decodeURI(url)** did not work correctly, however, **decodeURIComponent(url)** worked perfectly removing all %2 %20 etc...
A kind of workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Suggestion of function with error handling:

```
const validUrl     = require('valid-url');

const fillPhotoUrl = function(p) { return (p && validUrl.isUri(p)) ? decodeURIComponent(p) : null; };
```

Then use it:

```
{ 
 ... 

 let url = fillPhotoUrl(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);

 ...
}
```

If you want to know the difference between decodeURI and decodeURIComponent, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri).