# Is there a problem to use decodeURIComponent to decoding the string witch coding with encode method

Tags: javascript, urlencode

Such as the title,I have try to coding a string with encodeURI method,and decoding the result with decodeURIComponent method.and then I found the decoding string same as the original string.So I want to know if all strings coding with encodeURI can be decoding using decodeURIComponent.

```
encodeURI("http://www.example.com?type=qqq&string=qqq+<>`www");
//"http://www.example.com?type=qqq&string=qqq+%3C%3E%60www"

decodeURIComponent("http://www.example.com?type=qqq&string=qqq+%3C%3E%60www");
//"http://www.example.com?type=qqq&string=qqq+<>`www"
```

Comment: What do you mean by encrypt/decrypt?  This isn't encryption, and why use decodeURIComponent versus just decodeURI?

Comment: Note you are using 2 different encode/decode methods, encodeURI should be decoded with decodeURI not decodeURIComponent, that would be for encodeURIComponent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri)

Comment: @PatrickEvans yeah,I know it's two different encode/decode method.but it will give the same result.so I want to know if result is always  the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output of all the functions:

Input string: `https://www.google.co.in/`

Output string from `encodeURI`: `https://www.google.co.in/`

Output string from `encodeURIComponent`: `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F`

Now you decode the result of `encodeURI` with `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent` it will give you the same result. But if you decode the result of `encodeURIComponent` it will give you following result.

Input string: `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F`

Output string from `decodeURI`: `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F`

Output string from `decodeURIComponent`: `https://www.google.co.in/`

So conclusion is **`decodeURIComponent` is designed to decode everything** so it is safe to use it as per its specification means `decodeURI` with `encodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent` with `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: So the answer to the current question is *"it will give you the same result"*? Something to back this up a bit more authoritative than 'I tried once and it worked like that'.