# How can I navigate to a path with percentage sign in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to navigate to a page which may contain a percentage (**%**) sign in the url. e.g `"www.domain.com/edit/name%"`

```
if (some condition is met then redirect) {
  let encodedString = encodeURIComponent(this.state.identifier);

  console.log(encodedString);

  return <Redirect push to={`/edit/${encodedString}`} />
}
```

and in the component we redirected to:

```
if (params && params.identifier) {
  this.setState({
    identifier: decodeURI(params.identifier)
  });
}
```

From the `console.log();` I can clearly see that `encodedString` provided that *`this.state.identifier` is `name%`* is `name%25`. However, when the condition for redirecting is met, I immediately get this error `URIError: Pathname "/edit/name%" could not be decoded. This is likely caused by an invalid percent-encoding.`

Is there a way for me to redirect to the uri in the case that the `/:identifier` has a percentage sign?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `decodeURI` method will think that it is the start of an encoding and when nothing follows, an error is thrown. Try the following snippet:

```js
const decodedParam = "text%";
const encodedParam = encodeURIComponent(decodedParam);

const encodedUrl = `/edit/${encodedParam}`;
const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(encodedUrl);

console.log({ encodedUrl, decodedUrl });
```

The above snippet used the `decodeURIComponent` method instead. You can check out the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/747700/8003058).