# Turn &amp into & using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

We are interpolating a URL onto our page, it is coming from Rails and gets automatically escaped like so:

```
"http://foo.bar/path?key=val&amp;key2=val2"
```

Notice `&amp;` is there where it should be `&`.

This URL no longer works properly.

We did get it working by using Rails' `raw` method which prevents the escaping.

But I would prefer to do this using Javascript, and I'm sure there's a way.

---

**I tried unescape, decodeURI, and decodeURIComponent, they don't work**

```
str = "http://foo.bar/path?key=val&amp;key2=val2"
decodeURIComponent(str) == str // true
decodeURI(str) == str // true
unescape(str) == str // true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri)

Comment: Just for your own reference, these encoded chars are called [**HTML Entities**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

Comment: @imvain2 neither of those work with `&amp;`