# Plotly Annotation Text: encoding the Hash (#) character in a URL

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash, urlencode

In a plotly dash app, I am adding a text annotation with a clickable link that has a hash in it.

```
topic = "Australia"  # might contain spaces
hashtag = "#" + topic

annotation_text=f"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q={urllib.parse.quote_plus(hashtag)}&src=typed_query&f=live\">{topic}</a>"
```

I need the output html to contain `"https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Australia&src=typed_query&f=live"` but I can't get the "#" character to encode properly. It gets double encoded to %2523.

---

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import urllib.parse

df = px.data.gapminder()
all_continents = df.continent.unique()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash.html.Div([
    dash.dcc.Checklist(
        id="checklist",
        options=[{"label": x, "value": x}
                 for x in all_continents],
        value=all_continents[4:],
        labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    dash.dcc.Graph(id="line-chart"),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("line-chart", "figure"),
    [Input("checklist", "value")])
def update_line_chart(continents):
    mask = df.continent.isin(continents)
    fig = px.line(df[mask],
                  x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
    annotations = []
    df_last_value = df[mask].sort_values(['country', 'year', ]).drop_duplicates('country', keep='last')
    for topic, year, last_lifeExp_value in zip(df_last_value.country, df_last_value.year, df_last_value.lifeExp):
        hashtag = "#" + topic
        annotations.append(dict(xref='paper', x=0.95, y=last_lifeExp_value,
                                xanchor='left', yanchor='middle',
                                text=f"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q={urllib.parse.quote_plus(hashtag)}&src=typed_query&f=live\">{topic}</a>",
                                # text=f"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=#{urllib.parse.quote_plus(topic)}&src=typed_query&f=live\">{topic}</a>",

                                font=dict(family='Arial',
                                          size=16),
                                showarrow=False))

    fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
    return fig


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When you run this and click on the text "Australia" at the end of the line graph, it should open up a twitter search page for #Australia.

---

What I've tried:

1. just using a bare "#" character:  `text=f"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=#{urllib.parse.quote_plus(topic)}&src=typed_query&f=live\">{topic}</a>"`

Here, the # character is not encoded as %23 in the output, which results in a broken link for twitter.

`https://twitter.com/search?q=#mytopic&amp;src=typed_query&amp;f=live`
[link](https://twitter.com/search?q=#mytopic&src=typed_query&f=live)

2. using quote_plus on the hashtag `text=f"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=#{urllib.parse.quote_plus(hashtag)}&src=typed_query&f=live\">{topic}</a>"`

Here, the %23 (the encoded # character) gets encoded again, resulting in %2523 in the output.

`https://twitter.com/search?q=%2523mytopic&amp;src=typed_query&amp;f=live`[link](https://twitter.com/search?q=%2523mytopic&src=typed_query&f=live)

---

**How do I get it to correctly encode the # (to %23) so I get**

`href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23mytopic&amp;src=typed_query&amp;f=live`

Comment: I tested your code and got the same result. It seems like the query part of the uri (after the `?`) is not escaped as it should be, and the whole is encoded as if there were no `?`. This is probably a bug in the the annotation text rendering. A workaround would be to override it via javascript.

Comment: It's a known bug: [plotly/plotly.js#4084](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug: [plotly/plotly.js#4084](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4084)

Offending line in plotly.js:

```js
nodeSpec.href = encodeURI(decodeURI(href));
```

- `decodeURI` doesn't decode `%23` (`decodeURIComponent` does).
- `encodeURI` doesn't encode `#` but encodes `%` (`encodeURIComponent` does both).

More on that: [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/747700/8601760)

## Workaround

You can override the built-in `encodeURI` to revert the encoding of `%` in `%23`:

```py
app._inline_scripts.append('''
_encodeURI = encodeURI;
encodeURI = uri => _encodeURI(uri).replace('%2523', '%23');
''')
```